# Selecting a Google Maps pin from the Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

We are working on testing an iOS game we've developed that requires a user to select a pin from Google Maps. Once the user selects a pin, a small screen will show up prompting the user to "Accept" or "Decline" traveling to that location (part of the game).

We have a team of developers who are running tests on this script in Xcode and are building automated tests to ensure evey potential path within the game loads properly.

Does anyone know how to write the proper code that will automatically allow the simulator to select a pin from Google Maps? When we try it (after using the record function) and re-run the tests, we recieve a "UI Testing Failure" Message.

We're working on Swift.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you show any code you have tried to test selecting a pin from Google Maps?

Comment: I have tried to automate touch events and even Apple maps is failing to do so. In the end (when running test cases) I have presented a special button somewhere on the UI. Pressing on that button selected the pin for me. Hack but solved the problem.